# User-defined conversion cannot specify return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, smart-pointers

I am implementing unqiue smart pointers with template and I keep getting the compiler error saying user-define conversion cannot specify the return type. Below is my code for both header and cpp files. The error occurs at line 15 of .h and line 48 of .cpp I have already tried using template  instead of using template  and it doesn't work either.

```
//header
#ifndef UNIQUE_SMART_POINTER_H
#define  UNIQUE_SMART_POINTER_H
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class UniqueSmartPointer
{
private:
    T *ptr;

public:
    UniqueSmartPointer(T * p = nullptr);
    UniqueSmartPointer(UniqueSmartPointer&ref);
    const T* get()const;
    T & operator* ();
    T * operator-> ();
    void reset(T *);
    T * release();
    bool operator bool();
    //void swap(T x);
    UniqueSmartPointer& operator=(UniqueSmartPointer& ref);
    UniqueSmartPointer& operator=(UniqueSmartPointer && ref);
};
#endif
```

And here is the cpp

```
#include "UniqueSmartPointer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
UniqueSmartPointer<T>::UniqueSmartPointer(T * p): ptr(p)
{

}
template<typename T>
const T* UniqueSmartPointer<T>::get()const
{
    return ptr;
}
template<typename T>
T & UniqueSmartPointer<T>::operator* ()
{
    return *ptr;
}
template<typename T>
T *  UniqueSmartPointer<T>::operator-> ()
{
    return ptr;
}
template<typename T>
void UniqueSmartPointer<T>::reset(T * p)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
    ptr = p;

}
template<typename T>
T * UniqueSmartPointer<T>::release()
{
    T * temp = ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
    return temp;
}
template<typename T>
bool UniqueSmartPointer<T>::operator bool()
{
    if (ptr)
        return true;

    return false;
}
template<typename T>
UniqueSmartPointer<T>& UniqueSmartPointer<T>::operator=(UniqueSmartPointer& ref)
{
    if (*this == &ref)
        return *this;
    if (ptr)
        delete ptr;
    ptr = ref.ptr;
    ref.ptr = nullptr;
}
template<typename T>
UniqueSmartPointer<T>::UniqueSmartPointer(UniqueSmartPointer<T> &ref)
{
    ptr = ref.ptr;
    ref.ptr = nullptr;
}
template<typename T>
UniqueSmartPointer<T> & UniqueSmartPointer<T>::operator=(UniqueSmartPointer<T> && ref)
{
    if (*this == &ref)
        return *this;
    if (ptr)
        delete ptr;

    ptr = ref.ptr;
    ref.ptr = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Make it just `operator bool();` The return type of `bool` is implied - it makes no sense for a user-defined conversion to `bool` to return anything else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) In particular, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16615725.

Comment: Off topic: your `UniqueSmartPointer` class is a template one; implement it in a cpp class is, usually, a bad idea. Suggestion: declare and define it in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool operator bool();
```

should simply be:

```
/*explicit*/ operator bool() /*const*/;
```

and so

```
template<typename T>
UniqueSmartPointer<T>::operator bool() const
{
    return ptr != nullptr;
}
```